# jQuery make whole div clickable on ajax content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got a Wordpress website and posts are loading dynamically. I've added this to the php file for single post :

HTML

```
<article>
    <div class="blog-item-holder">
        <div class="featured-image">
            <a href></a>
        </div> Conent
    </div>
</article>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      $(".blog-item-holder").click(function(){
        window.location=$(this).find("a:first").attr("href"); 
        return false;
});
$(".blog-item-holder").css( "cursor", "pointer" );
```

but after the content has loaded dynamically, next posts are without this script. Is it a good idea to use jQuery `.on()`? How this code should look like in order to work?

Comment: Yes, `on` should work. What does your HTML look like?

Comment: @nbrooks '<article>
<div class="blog-item-holder"><div class="featured-image"><a href></a></div>
Conent</div>
</article>'

Comment: You should add details like that to the question, not in a comment. I've edited your question to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with `on` is a good idea. Something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on("click", ".blog-item-holder", function(){
        window.location=$(this).find("a:first").attr("href"); 
        return false;
    });

    $(".blog-item-holder").css( "cursor", "pointer" );

});
```

This only works if window.location is not refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery .on()

```
$(".blog-item-holder").on("click", function(){
        window.location=$(this).find("a:first").attr("href"); 
        return false;
});
```

Comment: this won't work for dynamically added `.blog-item-holder` elements, you'll need to use event delegation for dynamic elements